# Remove rows in dataframe based on other dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several datasets. One include a list of users, while the others are the activities of said users. The issues is that some of the users needs to be removed (admins, tests users, etc).

```
## Save users that should be removed
invalid_user = users[(users['E-Code'].isnull())]
## Remove users
user = users.drop(users[(users['E-Code'].isnull())].index)
```

Now I'm looking to remove the invalid users from other datasets. I cannot use the E-Code column as it is not present in the other datasets, I have to use another ID (unqiue id from a db). Currently, I'm looking into a datasets where the users logins are tracked. What I've tried unsuccessfully:

```
df = logins[logins['user_id'] != invalid_users['ID']]
```

and

```
df = logins['user_id'].drop(invalid_patients['ID])
```

Since I need to do this several times, I look to create a method once I get it down. I can't share the data, but I could create a example if it's needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `isin`

```
df = logins[~logins['user_id'].isin( invalid_users['ID'])]
```